# NSRange freezing app

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

```
NSString *originalString = entriesResultStr;
NSRange jarvisRange = [originalString rangeOfString:@"favoriteCount"];
NSString* substring = [originalString substringToIndex:jarvisRange.location];
```

For some reason, when I use NSRange, my app window won't open, but when I comment it out, my app opens fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `@"favoriteCount"` isn't in `originalString` and `jarvisRange` is being set to `{ NSNotFound, 0 }`.

Answer (score 0):

**What do you have in `originalString`?**

It would help if you explained what is in your `originalString` and what are you trying to achieve.

From what I see, **the `substring` should contain a substring from `originalString` starting from beginning up to the `favoriteCount`**.

- Is that what you were trying to do?
- What do you do with the `substring` after that?